# Travis + Appveyor

Tags: python, travis-ci, appveyor

I am using travis stages and would like to somehow include the appveyor build result as a precondition for deployment.

Is there any integration or script already available that does this? python would be ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this can help to start AppVeyor build and wait for result. Sorry I am more comfortable with PowerShell but it should be easy to translate to Python.

```
$token="<Your_api_token>"
$accountName="<Your_account>"
$projectSlug="<Your_project_slug>"
$branch="<Your_branch>"
$commitId="<Your_commit_id>"

$headers = @{
  "Authorization" = "Bearer $token"
  "Content-type" = "application/json"
}

$body = @{
    accountName=$accountName
    projectSlug=$projectSlug
    branch=$branch
    commitId=$commitId
}

$body = $body | ConvertTo-Json

$newBuild = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://ci.appveyor.com/api/builds' -Headers $headers  -Body $body -Method POST

$success = $false;
while(!$success) {
$status = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://ci.appveyor.com/api/projects/$accountName/$projectSlug/build/$($newBuild.version)" -Headers $headers  -Method GET).build.status
write-host "Status: $status"
$success = $status -eq "success"
if (($status -eq "failed") -or ($status -eq "cancelled")) {throw}
sleep 2
}
```

Comment: No worries. The reason I asked for Linux is because we want to keep Travis as the main CI server. But yes. Your example is very useful

Comment: What? This script? No, I just put it together for you. For production I would add more tracing and also timeout to the `while` loop.